# Run URLConnection uc in JavaFX Webview

Tags: java, url, webview, connection, javafx

I would like to load webpages in `JavaFX` `Webview` through a specified `URLConnection`.

This is the `UrlConnection`:

```
URLConnection uc;
        String urlString = u;
        url = new URL(urlString);
        uc = url.openConnection();
        uc.addRequestProperty("User-Agent",
                "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.0)");

        uc.connect();
        uc.getInputStream();
```

and this is the `WebView` I'm using:

```
Viewer.getEngine().load("https://www.google.com");
```

I would like to use this:

```
 uc.addRequestProperty("User-Agent",
                "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.0)");
```

because some pages aren't loading for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use [Java 8](https://jdk8.java.net/download.html), you can [set the WebView user agent](http://download.java.net/jdk8/jfxdocs/javafx/scene/web/WebEngine.html#setUserAgent-java.lang.String-) string directly on the `WebEngine`, so you probably don't need a custom [URLConnection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html) if that is all you want to achieve.